# Splitting multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
olddf <- structure(list(test = structure(1:6, .Label = c("test1", "test2", 
"test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"), class = "factor"), month0_gp1 = c("163±28", 
"133±20", "177±29", "153±30", "161±31", "159±23"), month0_gp2 = c("122±17", 
"167±20", "146±26", "150±27", "148±33", "161±37"), month1_gp1 = c("157±32", 
"152±37", "151±24", "143±25", "144±29", "126±30"), month1_gp2 = c("181±14", 
"133±34", "152±38", "144±30", "148±20", "137±19"), month3_gp1 = c("139±38", 
"161±39", "166±38", "162±39", "151±38", "155±38"), month3_gp2 = c("151±40", 
"161±33", "137±25", "161±31", "168±30", "147±34")), .Names = c("test", 
"month0_gp1", "month0_gp2", "month1_gp1", "month1_gp2", "month3_gp1", 
"month3_gp2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

   test month0_gp1 month0_gp2 month1_gp1 month1_gp2 month3_gp1 month3_gp2
1 test1     163±28     122±17     157±32     181±14     139±38     151±40
2 test2     133±20     167±20     152±37     133±34     161±39     161±33
3 test3     177±29     146±26     151±24     152±38     166±38     137±25
4 test4     153±30     150±27     143±25     144±30     162±39     161±31
5 test5     161±31     148±33     144±29     148±20     151±38     168±30
6 test6     159±23     161±37     126±30     137±19     155±38     147±34
```

I have to split columns 2:7 into 2 each (one for mean and other for sd):

```
test month0_gp1_mean month0_gp1_sd month0_gp2_mean month0_gp2_sd month1_gp1_mean month1_gp1_sd  ....
```

I checked earlier posts and used `do.call(rbind...`  method:

```
mydf <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(olddf$month0_gp1,'±')))

mydf
   X1 X2
1 163 28
2 133 20
3 177 29
4 153 30
5 161 31
6 159 23
```

But this works for one column at a time. How can I modify this to loop for 2:7 columns, and combine them to form one new dataframe? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, get [my `cSplit` function from this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733).

Second, split it up:

```
cSplit(olddf, 2:ncol(olddf), sep = "±")
#     test 2_1 2_2 3_1 3_2 4_1 4_2 5_1 5_2 6_1 6_2 7_1 7_2
# 1: test1 163  28 122  17 157  32 181  14 139  38 151  40
# 2: test2 133  20 167  20 152  37 133  34 161  39 161  33
# 3: test3 177  29 146  26 151  24 152  38 166  38 137  25
# 4: test4 153  30 150  27 143  25 144  30 162  39 161  31
# 5: test5 161  31 148  33 144  29 148  20 151  38 168  30
# 6: test6 159  23 161  37 126  30 137  19 155  38 147  34
```

If you want to do the column renaming in the same step, try:

```
Nam <- names(olddf)[2:ncol(olddf)]
setnames(
  cSplit(olddf, 2:ncol(olddf), sep = "±"), 
  c("test", paste(rep(Nam, each = 2), c("mean", "sd"), sep = "_")))[]
```

---

Another option would be to look at `dplyr` + `tidyr`.

Here's the best I could come up with, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this with these tools....

```
olddf %>%
  gather(GM, value, -test) %>%          # Makes the data somewhat long
  separate(value, c("MEAN", "SD")) %>%  # Splits "value" column. We're wide again
  gather(MSD, value, -test, -GM) %>%    # Makes the data long again
  unite(var, GM, MSD) %>%               # Combines GM and MSD columns
  spread(var, value)                    # Goes from wide to long
```

This is sort of the equivalent of `melt`ing the data once, using `colsplit` on the resulting "value" column, `melt`ing the data again, and using `dcast` to get the wide format.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a qdap approach:

```
library(qdap)
for(i in seq(2, 13, by = 2)){
    olddf <- colsplit2df(olddf, i, 
        paste0(names(olddf)[i], "_", c("mean", "sd")), sep = "±")
}

olddf[,-1] <- lapply(olddf[,-1], as.numeric)
olddf
```

I looked at Ananda's `splitstackshape` package first as I figured there was an easy way to do this but I couldn't figure out a way.

Not sure if you need the last line converting the columns to numeric but assumed you would.

Comment: `concat.split.multiple`, but `cSplit` is *much* faster.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks :-) I figured there was a way.  Is `cSplit` going to find its way into `splitstackshape` under that name or as a reboot of `concat.split.multiple`?

Comment: Actually, it seems like `±` doesn't work as a `sep` in `concat.split.multiple`. :-( I think `concat.split`.multiple` will be deprecated eventually in favor of `cSplit`.